# Color issues with vim in tmux over ssh.

Tags: vim, terminal, tmux, gnome-terminal

I am having an issue with tmux and vim where the background colors differ, but only when I am ssh'd into another machine. No solutions for posted questions I've found so far have worked for me.

[image]

On the left is my local machine, the right is when I'm ssh'd into my devbox. This is one tmux session.

On both machines:

- TERM is set to "screen-256color"
- using bash
- .vimrc contains `set term=screen-256color`
- .tmux.conf contains `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

I'm using Gnome. The background color in tmux when I'm in ssh and just using the cli is normal, this only occurs when I open vim and it returns to the normal color scheme when I exit.

Comment: If you don't use tmux and just SSH into it, does it look correct? Do you have anything in your `~/.vim/` directory on any of the machines?

Comment: Thank you, I feel so silly for not checking this. It was actually a problem caused by a system `.vimrc` being sourced, and I've (mostly) fixed it by adding `colo default` in my own `.vimrc`. I was tunnel visioned convinced it had to be a tmux issue, since many others have had similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by using `colo default` in my `.vimrc`. I was tunnel visioned convinced it was a tmux issue, and completely forgot vim was sourcing a system `.vimrc` on the remote box.